# Copy only rows with data to last empty row on a different sheet while ignoring formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy rows with data from a Master sheet and pasting them into the last empty row of History sheet. Each row will be one input and the data start on cells between A3:J3. Some of the cells have formulas on it which is causing issues with how i find the last row with data, both on the Master sheet and History sheet. Both Sheets have the same format. This is as far as i got:

```
Sub CopyToAnotherSheet()
Sheets("Master").Range("A3:J50").Copy
Sheets("History").Activate
Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng1 As Range
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng1 = ws.Columns(1).Find("*", ws.[a1], xlFormulas, , xlByColumns, xlPrevious)
          rng1.Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

It will copy a range and paste it at the end of the last range copied across.

Comment: first empty after end of current data as opposed to last empty? Are you actually trying to find the last used row in any given sheet?

Comment: Yes, last used row on sheet History so i can paste the rows with data from Master .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `rng1 =` line to:

```
Set rng1 = ws.rows(ws.Columns(1).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1)
```

Comment: By doing that, it does paste in the correct place, but it asks: ''There's already data here. Do you want to replace it?'' The only thing in those rows is a formula in the first column.

Comment: @AndrePereira add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` before you paste, then set it to `True` after you paste.

Comment: That sorted it. Thank you very much for your help. Is there an 'easy' way to copy only the rows with visible data in, within a range?